# How to make this list item "zoom"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I am trying to make list items "zoom" when selected.  I'm having trouble finding the best way to make this happen.  I'm using GSAP and the javascript is working just fine, but I'm having a hard time finding which property would best achieve the desired "zoom" effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/Leahp374/1/

At the moment, I am attempting to use CSS `perspective` and `translate3d` to move the item closer in the Z direction.  However, since the `perspective-origin` is at `50% 50%`, and since the list item is centered in its parent container, the first and last list items move towards the top and bottom, respectively.  Instead, I'd like them to all behave as the middle list item.

Using something like `font-size` will cause the element to 're-center' based on it's new width, which is not desirable.

What is the best way to achieve the "zoom" effect?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Leahp374/2/

Comment: @Rayon, thank you.  The javascript wasn't the issue.  I was wondering what CSS property would be best to animate.  I have just found it however:  `scale`.

Comment: I would somehow set a width on the `ul`. That way you can use `font-size` and let the text overflow so it doesn't _re-center_. [Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Leahp374/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the desired 'zoom' effect that you are looking for?
You can use scale transform along with transform origin to get the desired zoom effect.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  perspective: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(1.5);
   transform-origin:-40%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not know about `transform-origin`.  This is great.  Thank you.